# Could not determine the dependencies while using com.onesignal:OneSignal sdk and com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk together

Tags: android, onesignal, facebook-audience-network

I am facing issue all the time while syncing the project. Error is gone if I do clean and sync again.
 What are the steps to follow to resolve this error?

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileProductionDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:productionDebugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.5
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > comscore.bintray.com: Name or service not known
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.1
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://comscore.bintray.com/Analytics/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/maven-metadata.xml'.
                  > comscore.bintray.com
```

My gradle dependency file

```
implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.12.5'

    //SlideUp Panel
    implementation 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.4.0'

    //Utility Project
    implementation project(':utility')

    //Leak Canary
    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.4'
    releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.4'
    implementation 'com.github.crosswall:Android-Coverflow:release-v1.0.5'
    implementation 'io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
    implementation "im.ene.toro3:toro:3.7.0.2901-SNAPSHOT"
    implementation 'org.ocpsoft.prettytime:prettytime:4.0.1.Final'

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.comscore:android-analytics:5.+"

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.42.0'
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'

    implementation("com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.3")

    implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:5.4.1.1'

    //Play services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:17.0.0'
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I think this is the same as this: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/issues/653